# Accidentally amzn-sagemaker-studiolab package & now have weird UI

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm very new to Studiolab and I was trying to uninstall some packages I installed with pip. I was lazy and found this script online that did this for me. I ran "python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt" followed by "python -m pip uninstall -r requirements.txt". In the process, I deleted a couple important packages including amzn-sagemaker-studiolab. Could you point me in the right direction as to how I may be able to reset my environment to the default one. I am entirely okay with starting fresh, like I never worked on the environment before but my UI right now is pretty unusable and I can't figure out how to re-install the packages I deleted.

Most of the information is present in the details.

[image]

Comment: #amazon-sagemaker-lab

Answer (score 0):

Here are the commands you can use to reinitialize Studio Lab environment:

1. Open Terminal from JupyterLab IDE
2. Make sure you are under your home directory
3. Run rm -rf ..?* .[!.]* * and restart your project runtime, that should reset it

If that still does not work, the only recommendation we have is to delete and recreate your account.